# Add a icon in the toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I want to add a icon at the left of title in toolbar, just like the action bar. For example:

```
android:logo="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
android:label="FirstPage"
```

But when I do the same thing with action bar in toolbar, the icon isn't shown.

This is what I want:

[image: Toolbar with icon]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Just add a icon at the left of toolbar.

Comment: ![](http://img.blog.csdn.net/20140604232000843?watermark/2/text/aHR0cDovL2Jsb2cuY3Nkbi5uZXQvZ3VvbGluX2Jsb2c=/font/5a6L5L2T/fontsize/400/fill/I0JBQkFCMA==/dissolve/70/gravity/SouthEast)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it programmatically after you set your `Toolbar` as support `ActionBar`:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if(actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.your_image);
}
```

Comment: Thank you,this is the answer that i want.

Answer (score 0):

getActionBar();

You're throwing the action bar away right there. getActionBar() returns an instance of ActionBar, which you then need to call setIcon() on. Like so:

ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.my_icon);